# How to scroll and find an element using pagefactory approach

Tags: java, android, appium, page-factory

I am using pagefactory model and used below code to find an element, it works perfectly when the element is visible on screen, however, it fails when it is not visible, I already tried the action method but that doesn't work for me.

public class ChooseVenuePage extends AbstractPage {

```
@FindBy(xpath = ("//android.widget.TextView[@text='<text>']"))
private static AndroidElement DeliveryVenue;

public static void clickOnDeliveryVenue() {
    DeliveryVenue.click();
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), new ChooseLevelsPage());
}

@FindBy(xpath = ("//android.widget.TextView[@text='<text>']"))
private static AndroidElement TestVenue;

public static void clickOnTestVenue() {
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(TestVenue).perform();
    TestVenue.click();
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), new MenuPage());
}
```

}

The element is at the bottom of the screen and I need to scroll. Any suggestions would be really appreciable.

Comment: Have you found any solution?